# Why isn't it writing to file?

Tags: c++

I created the program below that reads 3 different files checks if they are sorted and then sorts them as while merges the A and B to a new file C. The program is working but the C file is empty even though there are data.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool is_sorted(ifstream & ifs)
{
    int a, b;

    ifs >> a;
    while (ifs.good())
    {
        ifs >> b;
        if (a > b)
        {
            return false;
        }
        a = b;
    }
    return true;
}

void merge_sorted(ifstream &ifs_a, ifstream &ifs_b, ofstream &ofs_c)
{
    int a, b;

    ifs_a >> a;
    ifs_b >> b;

    while (ifs_a.good() && ifs_b.good())
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            ofs_c << a << endl;
            ifs_a >> a;
        }
        else
        {
            ofs_c << b << endl;
            ifs_b >> b;
        }
    }

    while (ifs_a.good())
    {
        ofs_c << a << endl;
        ifs_a >> a;
    }

    while (ifs_b.good())
    {
        ofs_c << b << endl;
        ifs_b >> b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream a1;
    ifstream a;
    ifstream b;
    ofstream c;

    a1.open("A1");
    a.open("A");
    b.open("B");
    c.open("C.txt");

    if (is_sorted(a1))
    {
        cout << "Filen A1 ar sorterad" << endl;
    }
    else { cout << "Filen A1 ar inte sorterad" << endl; }
    if (is_sorted(a))
    {
        cout << "Filen A ar sorterad" << endl;
    }
    else { cout << "Filen A ar inte sorterad" << endl; }
    if (is_sorted(b))
    {
        cout << "Filen B ar sorterad" << endl;
    }
    else { cout << "Filen B ar inte sorterad" << endl; }


    if (is_sorted(a) && is_sorted(b))
    {
        merge_sorted(a, b, c);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "En av filerna ar inte sorterade" << endl;
    }

    c.close();

    ifstream c1;
    c1.open("C");

    if (is_sorted(c1))
    {
        cout << "Filen C ar sorterad" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Filen C ar inte sorterad" << endl;
    }

    a1.close();
    a.close();
    b.close();
    c1.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After `is_sorted` function, file stream has reached its end. All subsequent reads will return nothing,. You are essentually trying to merge two empty streams.

You will need to rewind your stream after you call is_sorted. Use [`seekg` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

```
file.seekg(0)
```